# Keep Getting An invalid term expression int

Tags: c#

```
class Typerwriter
{
    public static string Type(params string[] words)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for ( int i = 0; int < words.Length; i++)

    {
        sb.Append(words[i]);
    }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

I'm a beginner and trying to figure this out and I keep  getting an invalid term expression int.  What is it that i'm doing wrong

Answer (score 5):

change `int < words.Length` to `i < words.Length`